# To use the equipment suffix "G", does the GPS have to be certified for IFR?

Tags: faa-regulations, instrument-flight-rules, flight-planning, equipment

To use the equipment suffix "G", does the GPS have to be certified for IFR flight?

Comment: What equipment suffix are you referring to?

Comment: See list of FAA equipment codes [here](http://www.faraim.org/aim/aim-4-03-14-276.html) or [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equipment_codes)

Comment: @selectstriker2 /G is the equipment suffix used in FAA IFR flight plans for GNSS plus mode C

Comment: In the US if you are just getting flight following, you can use the /G suffix when making your request to ATC. However, in 20 years of using flight following on almost every flight, I have never had ATC give me anything but a heading to follow so it really doesn’t matter what you use.

Comment: @JScarry That's interesting, why do you include equipment details in a fight following request?

Comment: @Pondlife That’s how I was taught 20 years ago and I never thought about it. I guess it’s a carry-over from filing a VFR flight plan when I was a student pilot. I’m guessing that back then there were still aircraft that were Mode A, so it was good to let ATC know that you were transmitting altitude. I probably don’t need to do it anymore since everyone is Mode C or S and lots of planes have ADSB.

Comment: @JScarry Thanks for sharing that. I think you're right about ATC making assumptions. I rarely hear pilots include their equipment suffix in a pop-up IFR request and ATC never asks for it. I guess they're just assuming that everyone is /G.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, using GPS for IFR requires a certified unit. The [AIM 1-1-17(b)(2) says](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/publications/atpubs/aim_html/chap1_section_1.html) (emphasis mine):

> Authorization to conduct any GPS operation under IFR requires:
>
> (1) GPS navigation equipment used for IFR operations must be approved in
>   accordance with the requirements specified in Technical Standard Order
>   (TSO) TSO-C129(), TSO-C196(), TSO-C145(), or TSO-C146(), and the
>   installation must be done in accordance with Advisory Circular AC
>   20-138, Airworthiness Approval of Positioning and Navigation Systems.
>   Equipment approved in accordance with TSO-C115a does not meet the
>   requirements of TSO-C129. **Visual flight rules (VFR) and hand-held
>   GPS systems are not authorized for IFR navigation, instrument
>   approaches, or as a principal instrument flight reference.**